# Combining several collection into line chart in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I made several collection and I want to make a line chart using these five period.

```
var p1 = S2.filterDate('2020-04-14','2020-04-27').mean();
Map.addLayer(p1.clip(SBY), band_viz, 'PERIODE 1');

var p2 = S2.filterDate('2020-04-28','2020-05-11').mean();
Map.addLayer(p2.clip(SBY), band_viz, 'PERIODE 2');

var p3 = S2.filterDate('2020-05-12','2020-05-25').mean();
Map.addLayer(p3.clip(SBY), band_viz, 'PERIODE 3');

var p4 = S2.filterDate('2020-05-26','2020-06-08').mean();
Map.addLayer(p4.clip(SBY), band_viz, 'PERIODE 4');

var p5 = S2.filterDate('2020-06-09','2020-06-22').mean();
Map.addLayer(p5.clip(SBY), band_viz, 'PERIODE 5');

var period = p1.addBands(p2).addBands(p3).addBands(p4).addBands(p5);


var options = {
 title: 'Grafik Rata-Rata Kadar NO2 Per Periode',
 hAxis: {title: 'Periode Waktu'},
 vAxis: {title: 'Rata-Rata Kadar NO2 (mol/m2)'},
 lineWidth: 1,
 pointSize: 4,
 };

var Periode = ['Periode 1', 'Periode 2', 'Periode 3', 'Periode 4', 'Periode 5'];

var chart = ui.Chart.image.regions(
  period, SBY, ee.Reducer.mean(), 30, 'label', Periode)
   .setChartType('ScatterChart')
   .setOptions(options);


print(chart);
```

But instead I got this
[image]

How can my chart to have just a single line representing the mean of each period?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of combining your periods to a single image, you can put them in an image collection and use `ui.Chart.image.series()`.

```
var periods = ee.ImageCollection([
  p1.set('period', 'Periode 1'),
  p2.set('period', 'Periode 2'),
  p3.set('period', 'Periode 3'),
  p4.set('period', 'Periode 4'),
  p5.set('period', 'Periode 5'),
])

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: periods, 
  region: SBY, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 30, 
  xProperty: 'period'
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/95cf279dbffa2c615fecb69b4fbd968a